# Picture not being stored inside mysql database properly

Tags: php, mysql

A value is being stored in the database but it is not the one i am expecting. I tried many methods before but this one kind of seems to work but the file name is not being stored and when I try to download the file directly from the database, it downloads a .bin file format which looks something like table_Name-column_Name.bin. The file name being stored is BLOB - ## B.

**My Form**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="productsValidate.php" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Add Product</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Product_Name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Product_Name" placeholder="Name" required="required" name="Product_Name">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Size" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Size</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Size" placeholder="Size" required="required" name="Size">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Color" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Color</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Color" placeholder="Size" required="required" name="Color">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="price" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Price</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="price" required="required" name="price">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="image" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Select Image</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="categoryId" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Category Id</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <?php
               //your connection to the db and query would go here
               include "../include/settings.php";
               $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $sql_db);
               if ($conn->connect_error) {
                   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
               }
               $sql = "SELECT distinct Category_Id FROM products";
               $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
               ?>
            <select id="categoryId" name="categoryId">
               <option value = ""></option>
               <?php
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<option value='.$row['Category_Id'].'>'.$row['Category_Id'].'</option>';
                  }
                  ?> 
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="description" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" required="required" name="description" pattern="[\sA-Za-z]+"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

**My Form validation**

```
    <?php

    $name = $_POST["Product_Name"];
    $size = $_POST["Size"];
    $color = $_POST["Color"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];

    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image = base64_encode($image);
    $image=basename( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],".jpg");

    $category = $_POST['categoryId'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    insertProduct($name, $size, $color, $price, $image, $category, $description);

    function insertProduct($name, $size, $color, $price, $image, $category, $description){

        require_once ("../include/settings.php");   // Load MySQL log in credentials
        $conn = @mysqli_connect ($host,$user,$pwd,$sql_db); // Log in and use database
        if ($conn) { // check is database is avialable for use
            $query = "INSERT INTO products
                                    (Product_Id, Product_Name, Size, Color, Price, Picture, Category_Id, Description)
                                VALUES ('', '$name', '$size', '$color', '$price', '$image', '$category', '$description')";

            $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
            if ($result) {                              // check if query was successfully executed
                echo 'Successfully Added';
            } else {
                echo 'Product could not be added';
            }
            mysqli_close ($conn);                   // Close the database connect
        } else {
            echo "<p>Unable to connect to our database for adding the product.</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

[image: Database]

Comment: It's often better to just upload the picture to a folder on the server, and store the path to it in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're trying to store the actual encoded image in the database, not a pointer to it. It looks to me like your eleven-byte BLOB has the pointer in it instead.

Your code contains this sequence of lines.

```
$image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image = file_get_contents($image);
$image = base64_encode($image);
$image=basename( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],".jpg");
```

The third line puts an encoded, not binary, version of the image into a text string. That's close to what you want, but you probably should not base64-encode it if you're putting in a BLOB.

The fourth line discards the image itself and overwrites it with an image name. I think that's wrong.

If you're going to use BLOB data this way, you also need to use mysqli's facilities to [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) your SQL statements, and then [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) your parameters. The [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function gives you a way to declare a parameter to be a blob. That's better than trying to trick php's string processing into accepting it.

All that being said, most people use a file system or content server rather than BLOBs to store and serve images to web clients. BLOB programming is a pain in the neck. Also, using a DBMS to store and retrieve images quickly becomes a performance bottleneck in an application that scales up.